# Prove that $A$ is regular matrix and find $A^{-1}$ if $A,I\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $(A+I)^3=O$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Expansion of a binomial gives:
$$A^3+3A^2+3A+I=0$$
We know that the matrix is regular if squared and has inverse ($detA\neq 0$).
Is it possible to determine from above equation that $detA\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically done.

Take $A^3+3A^2+3A+I=0$ and rearrange it to get $I = -A^3 - 3A^2 - 3A$.

We then have that

$A(-A^2-3A-3I)=I$

and so $A$ is invertible and its inverse is

$A^{-1}=-A^2-3A-3I$

Answer (score 2):

you can see from $$A(-A^2 - 3A - 3I) = I  $$ that $$A^{-1} = -A^2 - 3A - 3I $$

since $(A+I)^3 = 0$ only eigenvalue is $-1,$ therefore the determinant of $A$ is $(-1)^n.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since: $A^3+3A^2+3A+I=0$, So the minimal polynomial of $A$, is a factor of $(x+1)^3$. Thus, the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $-1$. So, $det(A)=(-1)^n\neq 0$.

Comment: The constant term of the minimal polynomial is not equal to $\det A$ in general. (Even for $A$ satisfying the conditions of this problem) For example, if $A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x+1$, which has constant term $1$. But $\det A = -1 \neq 1$. We can, however, conclude that $A$ is invertible because the constant term of the minimal polynomial is not $0$.

Comment: While it is true for matrices $A$ which satisfy $(A+I)^3=0$ that the constant term of the minimal polynomial is $(-1)^n \det A$, it is still not true in general. It is only true in this case because all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$, and so the determinant of $A$ is $(-1)^n$. If we consider $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$, though, then the minimal polynomial of $B$ is $(x-1)(x-2)$ which has constant term $2$. But $\det B=4$. So while what you have written is true specifically in the context of this problem, it is not true in general.

Comment: I think that you may be thinking about the result which says that the determinant of a matrix is equal to the constant term of the *characteristic* polynomial. Fortunately, we do not need to know exactly how the determinant of $A$ relates to the constant term of the minimal polynomial, just that if the constant term of the minimal polynomial is not $0$ then neither is the determinant.